# Linq to sql search query : Issues with a "struct" type

Tags: c#, linq, struct

I'm trying to create a search function using Linq to Sql.

I have a Sale class, with an AnimalId, and an Animal class, with a structure called "AgeStruct". This structure is stored as a string ("AgeDB") into the Animal table, and defines operators (<, ==, >) to be able to know who is the oldest or the youngest.
The Animal's "Age" property is returning an AgeStruct based on the "AgeDB" value.

```
public partial class Animal
{
    public AgeStruct Age
    {
        get { return new AgeStruct(AgeDB); }
        set { AgeDB = value.ToFormat(); }
    }

    public struct AgeStruct : IComparable
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My search function takes a SaleCriteria instance as parameter, which notably contains an Age property, of "AgeStruct" type.

In my where clause, I want to return all animals older than the criteria.Age, but the following is returning :

> "Could not format node 'new' for execution as SQL"

```
public static List<Sale> Search(SaleCriteria criteria)
{
    var db = new DBDataContext();
    if (criteria.Age != null)
    {
          result = (System.Linq.IQueryable<Sale>)
             from sale in db.Sale
             join animal in db.Animal on sale.AnimalId equals animal.Id
             where new Animal.AgeStruct(animal.AgeDB) > criteria.Age
             select sale;
    }
}
```

I also tried this :

```
where Animal.Age > criteria.Age
```

but obviously "Age" is not a column, and Linq is complaining.

I could also do this :

```
where Animal.AgeDB > criteria.Age.ToFormat()
```

but the ">" operator is not available for string type and may not returning the correct result anyway.

Would anybody has an idea of how I could resolve this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You've got all your logic in C# code within `Animal`. LINQ to SQL can't convert that into SQL. You either need to perform the filtering client-side, or store the data in a more appropriate form in SQL so you can filter it there.

Comment: The simplest solution is to store the age as a number. If it is a compound type it probably needs to be stored in a separate table and referenced with a foreign key. Not serialized into a string.

Comment: Thanks Jon and Jodrell ! I don't think I could store it as one number since I've got the number of years and the number of months in my struct, but I could do this with two columns "years" and "months" rather than creating a new table with a foreign key. If there is no solution with the current implementation I'll do so !